# Get all categories post is not in

Tags: php, terms, categories

I am trying to get a list of all categories that the current post is *not* in. I made it this far...

```
$categories = get_the_category( $post_id );
$nocats = get_terms('category', array('exclude' => $categories) );
foreach ( $nocats as $nocat ) {echo $nocat->name;echo ","; }
```

...but it's not working. I guess it has to do with imploding the `$categories` array, but the thing threw an error when I tried this...

```
$categories = get_the_category( $post_id );
$excats = implode(',', $categories);
$nocats = get_terms('category', array('exclude' => $excats) );
foreach ( $nocats as $nocat ) {echo $nocat->name;echo ","; }
```

... so now I'm stuck. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. So, the first bit of code is more correct but it has issues nonetheless. Piece by piece...

```
$categories = get_the_category( $post_id );
```

`$post_id` is not set in the code you posted. I assume that value is set earlier in the page somewhere, else that is your first problem.

```
$nocats = get_terms('category', array('exclude' => $categories) );
```

The `exclude` argument will accept an array of term IDs, but that is not what `get_the_category()` returns. It returns an array of objects. You cannot use that as is. (This, by the way, is the same reason you are having trouble with `$excats = implode(',', $categories);`. You are trying to convert objects into strings). You need to extract the IDs:

```
$categories = wp_list_pluck($categories,'term_id');
```

Then:

```
$nocats = get_terms('category', array('exclude' => $categories) );
```

There is one further step: `get_terms()` by default will only return categories that have posts assigned to them. If you truly want to show all categories you need to add `'hide_empty' => false` to your argument list:

```
$nocats = get_terms(
  'category', 
  array(
    'exclude' => $categories,
    'hide_empty' => false
  ) 
);
```

Now your code should work:

```
$categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );
// var_dump($categories);
$categories = wp_list_pluck($categories,'term_id');
// var_dump($categories);
$nocats = get_terms(
  'category', 
  array(
    'exclude' => $categories,
    'hide_empty' => false
  ) 
);
// var_dump($nocats);
foreach ( $nocats as $nocat ) {
  echo $nocat->name;
  echo ","; 
}
```